# Open Source Text Localization Library

Tags: java, javascript, python, localization

Is there an open source project that handles the process of localizing tokenized string text to other languages, and has complex handling for grammar, spelling (definite, indefinite, plural, singular), also for languages like german handling of masculine, feminine, neuter.

Most localization frameworks do wholesale replace of strings and don't take into account tokenized strings that might refer to objects that in some languages could be masculine/feminine/neuter.

The programming language I'm looking for is Javascript/Java/Actionscript/Python, it'd be nice if there was a programming-language independent data-format for creating the string tables.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I've not heard of any such a framework.

From the limited amount that I understand and have heard about this topic, I'd say that this is beyond the state of the art ... certainly if you are trying to do this across multiple languages.

Here are some relevant resources:

- ["Open-Source Software and Localization"](http://www.project-open.com/whitepapers/oss-l10n/) by Frank Bergman [2005]
- Plural forms in GNU gettext - http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gettext/Plural-forms.html